# What is the best way to load an embedded video from a link on the same page (YouTube Search/Player APIs)

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I appreciate any assistance you can provide me with. I believe I have included all necessary code I've created so far so that the provided background will fill in any gaps.

Background: A school assignment requires me to create a page where a user can enter a search, which is then sent to the YouTube search URL via PHP on the server side (I'm pretty sure I could have just used JS on the same page for it, but they want me to use ajax), and then load the results on the page where the user searched. The user should then be able to click on one of those links, and have the video play embedded on the same page.

So far: I have successfully got the search data from my php file via Ajax and the return function creates html for the list of search results.

```
        // send to php, if successful load video results from return info

        $.ajax({
            url: "ytSearch.php",
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {

        // create list of search results on page using info 
        // from "items" array in the search result

            var searchResults = JSON.parse(response);
            var videos = new Array();
            videos = searchResults.items;
            console.log(videos);
            $("#ytVideo").append("<ul class='media-list ts-video-container>");

        // possibly use 'a' element for search result to be clicked on
            $.each(videos, function (key, value) {
                $("#ytVideo").append("<a class='clickPlay'>"
                    //+ value.id.videoId + "'>"
                    + "<li class='media btn-link youtube-video'>" 
                    + "<img src=" + value.snippet.thumbnails.default.url
                    + " alt='' class='img-responsive'>"
                    + "<h5 class='ytList'>" + value.snippet.title + "</h5></br>"
                    + "<p class='ytListDesc'>" + value.snippet.description
                    + "</p></li></a>");

                });
                $("#ytVideo").append("</ul>");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('p.phpresults').html(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }        
        });
```

I have also successfully loaded the player on the page in a different div element, which is working. I kept that JS separate from this tag.

**I need to be able to** click on the search result, access the videoID property for that search result and send it to the function to load the video in the player. This is where I'm trying to figure out what the best way to do that would be.

I've created an event listener for the  element in my search results, but I'm stuck on how I would somehow access the videoID property through that in order to send it to the loadVideoById function in the Youtube Player API.

```
    $(document).on("click", "a", function(){

        console.log("click worked");
    
    });
```

One thing I am considering: should I create objects for each search result from the data, **then** use those to create the html to display the search results? Would that make it easier to access those objects and the properties I need to send to the player?

Thank you
CK

Answer (score 0):

This was done by adding the global "data-" attribute  to the  element for each search result, and referencing the videoId from the YouTube search data:

```
            $.each(videos, function (key, value) {
                $("#ytVideo").append(
                    "<li class='media btn-link youtube-video' data-videoid='" + value.id.videoId + "'>" 
                    + "<img src=" + value.snippet.thumbnails.default.url
                    + " alt='' class='img-responsive'>"
                    + "<h5 class='ytList'>" + value.snippet.title + "</h5></br>"
                    + "<p class='ytListDesc'>" + value.snippet.description
                    + "</p></li>");
```

The script for loading the video when the `<li>` element is clicked is:

```
    $(document).on("click", "li", function(){

        player.loadVideoById($(this).data('videoid'), 0);
    });
```

CK